# Photographic Companions

Tags: word, lateral-thinking

What do we all need to breathe which connects the concepts of "photographic equipment" and "companion", based on the etymology of their synonyms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming the answer is

> ROOM

Based on the previous answer explanations

> Camera comes from the Greek KAMARA meaning ROOM. Comrade also comes from the Greek KAMARA meaning ROOM.

So,

> For example the old saying, "I need some room to breathe." or "Give me some room to breathe."

Comment: This one is good too, now "all need to breathe" have already 3 different interpretations (the oxygen the carbondioxide and your "room") which all make sense:) Now I wonder what the intended answer is:)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'm sure we each would say our own:)

Comment: Actually no, I find yours more complete and unique. Also there is a tag "word". It is a good abstraction puzzle.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your vote of confidence. And I agree, I also saw more word-play than science in the question. And that saying was actually the first thing that popped into my head when I read it.

Comment: A perfect solution :-)

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer, I was sure you've got the right solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

"photographic equipment" refers to

> CAMERA, whose [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camera#Etymology) goes back to Latin ["camera" meaning chamber](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camera#Latin) and Ancient Greek ["kamara"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek).

"companion" refers to

> COMRADE, whose [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comrade#Etymology) goes back to [the same Latin word "camera"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camera#Latin) and [Ancient Greek "kamara"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek).

So we've got a couple of cognates; how does that connect to what we all need to breathe?

> The best option I can find is CARBON. [Not etymologically connected](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carbon#Etymology), it seems, but a vaguely similar word, and the chemical symbol is **C** which stands for "camera".

Comment: ⅔ of the solution.  But who needs carbon to breathe?

Answer (score 4):

> O2 because "chamber" and "comrade" (sharing the same room) both might refer to carbon dioxide, but the close companion of it (remaining in the context) is O2. This fulfills the phrasing "need to breathe" too. (Also, if people share the same room there will be more Co2, less O2, they will need more O2).

EDIT

maybe I overcomplicated it, and it is just

> CO2

because

> if "need to breathe" means a negative consequence of staying in the same room together.

Comment: You do not need CO₂ to breathe.  You exhale it, exactly for the reason that you do _not_ need it.

Comment: Sure, there should have been "have to" to fit this. We generally use the same word in hungarian, you use many words in English (or German. Actually I just realized that you _do_ need exactly CO2 to breath and sometimes to inhale as well but this leads to another topic :D